# ListView ScrollAble Area

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, scrollable

Is there a way to remove the annotation

> This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless;
>   transfer the background attribute to the other   view

that I have in my xml file and keep the same output?

I am using the xml file with a custom Adapter to set notifications on ListView

If I change the listview(see below) width to the @dimen/notification_width(notifications size) it can go the the center of the screen but then empty area (right and left of notification) isn't scrollable.

How can I remove the annotation and keep the scrollable area?

P.S. IDE Eclipse

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/borders" >

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/notify_start"
            android:id="@+id/notificationText"
            style="@style/TextLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/notificationText"
            android:text="@string/button_move_to" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

after removing the linear layout or relative layout
[image]
(removed linear layout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/borders"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/notify_start"
        android:id="@+id/notificationText"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/notificationText"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        android:text="@string/button_move_to" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(removed relative layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/borders">


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/notify_start"
        android:id="@+id/notificationText"
        style="@style/TextLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notificationBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:text="@string/button_move_to" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/notificationList"
    style="@style/CustomScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/scroolbar_margin"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/spacer_height" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ScrollView   
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:fillViewport="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"   
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <ListView
 android:id="@+id/notificationList"
 style="@style/CustomScroller"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="@dimen/scroolbar_margin"
 android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
 android:dividerHeight="@dimen/spacer_height" />
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: but isn't good practice to use a listview inside a scrollview.